# APNS iOS Push notifications not working after app ownership transfer using p8 certificate

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, app-transfer, p8

After app ownership transfer completed, push notifications stopped working and I am getting this error :

```
{"reason":"DeviceTokenNotForTopic"}
```

the request/response  :

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600003684120> 
{URL: https://api.push.apple.com:443/3/device/85E1815D3F181CD04DBE1B45CD0F8A3FC3252091E85AA96842A20B34*********} 
{ Status Code: 400, Headers {"apns-id" =   ("6A57183E-860C-EB8B-0968-5581B88421E9");
} }
```

Documentation and apple support stated that the old P8 certificate should continue working after transfer, but it's not.

Any idea?
Thank you.